# Send a message to my microcontroller using Netcat - C language

Tags: c, linux, tcp, esp8266, netcat

I've searched a lot and wasn't able to figure out how to solve my question. I have an esp8266 12E configured to receive a message through TCP/IP and activate a door if the message sent have the right password. I have the following code:

```
system ("netcat 192.168.4.1 555");
```

After executing on terminal netcat is open, but I'm not able to figure out how to let my program write the password automatically. Tried:

```
system ("netcat 192.168.4.1 555");
printf("key");
```

It wasn't able to write something after calling the netcat command. And after my program send the key it is needed to close netcat, how to do it?

I hope that I could explain myself in english, and would be glad getting help to solve this simple problem.

*I'm coding using linux, and my app will run on a raspberry pi.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your issue correctly but you could directly send your message to netcat with the `echo` command : `system("echo \"key\" | netcat 192.168.4.1 555")`

Comment: Hi @Storm , thanks for your comment. I was thinking in let the user click on the "connect" button and keep connected with the door, and then when someone arrive the door will open automatically when the microcontroller receive my app message.

Comment: Then you might be better off implementing your own TCP client in your code, rather than trying to pipe it all through to netcat.

Comment: Try adding option `-q 0` to force netcat to close after end of transmission

Comment: @Storm , Understand. I've tried what you did say before. [code]system("echo \"key\" | netcat 192.168.4.1 555")[/code] Even by that way, that netcat still open after send the message, cant terminate the program.

Comment: Or with option `-w0` to set timeout to 0 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`popen` is your friend.  It's similar to `system`, but returns a "file pointer" (in inverted commas!) which you can read/write from/to.

Several examples of its use [can be found online](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html).

**Untested pseudo-example**:

```
fp = popen("nc 192.168.4.1 555", "w");
if (fp == NULL) {
   /* Handle error */
   printf("Couldn't spawn nc\n");
   exit(1);
}
fprintf(fp, "key"); // write to netcat's STDIN
pclose(fp);
```

Alternatively you could open a network socket and read/write to the network directly yourself: i.e. http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~eddiea/samples/IOMultiplexing/TCP-client.c.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @wally answer and @Stom comment. Both let me to understand how that functionality works and so I was able to solve my problem. I was facing too much problem letting my app keep connected with the microcontroller. So now I prefer to only send the message and terminate netcat.

When I run the code below I can only send one message and need to restart the app manually. But it was a great help to reach the solution.

```
fp = popen("nc 192.168.4.1 555", "w");
if (fp == NULL) {
   /* Handle error */
   printf("Couldn't spawn nc\n");
   exit(1);
}
fprintf(fp, "key"); // write to netcat's STDIN
pclose(fp);
```

The code below is called when I click the "Open Door" button.

```
FILE *fp;
  int ch;
  char txt[20];
  int value;
  char comando[] = "";
  int len=0;
  fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");
  if(fp){
    do{
    ch=fgetc(fp);
    txt[len]=ch;
    len++;
  }while(ch !=EOF && ch != '\n');
  fclose(fp);
}
  value = atoi(txt);
  sprintf(comando, "echo %d | timeout 3 nc 192.168.4.1 555",value);
  system(comando);
```

The file with password is opened, the content is stored on a variable and sent using netcat.

Adding "timeout 3" netcat waits for 3 seconds before close connection. It allows me to click the button again and close or open the door how many time I want to.

```
echo %d | timeout 3 nc 192.168.4.1 555
```

I needed to copy the content of "char txt" to "int value", because on terminal instead of writing the password number, it was writing "cho cho".